# Is it possible to share a USB GPS dongle with multiple Docker containers?

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, gps, usb

I am using a VK-172 U-Blox AG GPS in my Raspberry Pi 3 as part of a receive-only APRS iGate.  I am running Docker on the RPi.  Right now I am running a Docker container that uses the GPS dongle for position data with Direwolf, which is reported to the APRS-IS network.

I would also like to run a Docker container to use the GPS as a very accurate time reference for other machines on my network.

Is it possible to share a USB GPS dongle with multiple Docker containers?

73 de K6JEB

Comment: "U-Blox AG GPS" does not lead search engines to the manufacturer product page so please be more specific. Ideally you should provide a link to the datasheet / user manual / product web page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[***Disclaimer***]
I'm not sure if you want to know how to share **any** USB device with a container or in particular this USB GPS dongle (because of some additional requirements, configuration etc). But I'll try to do my best.

**Add singe USB device**

If you want to add a USB device (that is plugged in host) to the container. You can use `--device` docker run option.

> **--device**      Add a host device to the container

You will need bus and device on which your device is connected to (use `lsusb` or `dmesg` to find that). Example:

Lets say I want to add this Yubikey to contaiener:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
....
Bus 001 Device 017: ID 1050:0010 Yubico.com Yubikey (v1 or v2)
```

then I would run container like so:

```
docker run -dit --device /dev/bus/usb/<BUS>/<DEVICE> <image>
docker run -dit --device /dev/bus/usb/001/017 <image>
```

Then this USB device will be accessible inside a container. Now for your use case add this option to containers which need to have access to that device.

**Please note!** you may need `--privileged` flag in order to have correct permissions.

> **--privileged**  Give extended privileges to this container

**Adding all USB devices**

You can also connect all available USB devices to a contiaer or containers by mounting whole `/dev/usb/bus` directory:

```
docker run -dit --privileged -v /dev/bus/usb:/dev/bus/usb <image>
```

Is this what you need?

Regards